# Visual Basic Time Variable for DTS packages

Tags: vb.net, dts

I am converting some DTS packages over from Visual Basic to C# and am wondering what @OldDate the following would produce. I am not a VB.NET guy and really do not have the time to play around with this..and it has to be correct so I am reaching out to SO!!

```
datActionDate = Now()
intNumberOfDays = 365
businessDays = 0

Set .ActiveConnection = objConnection
    .CommandType = 4
    .CommandText = strStoredQuery
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@OldDate",7,1,8,CDate(datActionDate))
    .Execute
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!!

*Edit the datActionDate is a number from a do loop. holidayLs is basically checking that date against a list of dates

```
do until bdays = intNumberOfDays
    datActionDate = DateAdd("d", -1, datActionDate)
    if weekday(datActionDate) > 1 and weekday(datActionDate) < 7 then
        if not holidayLs(datActiondate) then
            businessDays = businessDays + 1
        end if
    end if
loop
```

Comment: What does 'what date' mean?

Comment: `@OldDate` is just a parameter name. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Yes, @OldDate is a parameter. What value would it be set to is what I am trying to figure out. It is being passed to a stored procedure in a DTS package. The CreateParameter method I was trying to understand also to figure out what OldDate is

Comment: Well, you didn't show us what object that is but it seems to be an `ADODB.Command`. In that case, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/createparameter-method-ado?view=sql-server-2017) would be the documentation of the `CreateParameter` method and it shows that the last argument is the value, which is `datActionDate` in this case.

Comment: Again, I am not a Visual Basic guy. That is why I was asking a question. I can see that I am going to have to spend some time on this

Comment: I believe you just didn't provide a clear question. You said that your question was _"what value will the parameter be set to"_ and I answered you: "whatever value in the `datActionDate` variable" which (based on the first block of code only) should be the current date at the time of executing the code (`Date()` is equivalent to `DateTime.Now`). You also wanted to understand the `CreateParameter` method and I provided you with a link to the documentation. If all that doesn't solve your problem (whatever it is), you should edit the question and try to provide a straightforward question.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. It just hit me the wrong way. I will delete.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I appreciate your response. I will try to refine my question when I understand more about the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After picking up a basic understanding about VB enough to read this code, I have found that this question is less about syntax and more about just working through the logic. The @OldDate will end up being a number around 470 days from today given

```
DateAdd("d", -1, datActionDate)
```

is subtracting a day from datActionDate which is defined as

```
datActionDate = Now()
```

I was unfamiliar with the weekday() which just yields a numerical day. So the following statement

```
if weekday(datActionDate) > 1 and weekday(datActionDate) < 7 then
```

Is basically looking for days that are not Saturday and Sundays (for which there are 105 in a year - which will be the MINIMUM decremented from today)

When subtracting holidays that are in the holidaysLs (for which there are about 11) in this line

```
if not holidayLs(datActiondate) then
```

Then datActionDate = Saturday, November 24, 2018